# Import math fails in IronPyhton

Tags: c#, math, ironpython

I am trying to use IronPython log function in C#. Idea is user would write a mathematical script this would be evaluated and answer would be displayed in UI. When I use this method for simple mathematics(addition, subtraction etc.) it works fine. When I need to use log function I try to import math module it fails. My code is:

```
public double Calculate(string script)
{
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("import math" + System.Environment.NewLine + script, SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect);
    return source.Execute<double>();
}
```

When I run this code I get exception 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException No Module named math`.
I am calling method as`
Calculate("math.log(10)")`

Am I missing any import or dll?

Comment: I think, if you imported math you can use just `Calculate("log(10)")` without `math`.

Comment: Thanks Hamlet, I have tried that doesn't work either.

Comment: Your post is not the real code... Your post contains "import math" with a lowercase m, the error you are receving will pop-up when using 'import Math' (uppercase m) instead. So basically, this code you are pasting is actually working :)

Comment: I was getting exception with math with lowercase 'm' with old version of IronPython and Microsoft.Script and Microsoft.Dynamic dlls. I am using lowercase m in math as I wanted to use Python math functions. For CSharp math functions you need to use "import System.Math". If you use just 'import Math' you would get exception all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue, however I did not have IronPython installed yet, so I installed the latest stable version (2.7.4) from [here](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/90087). I am not sure if you are using the same version...

When creating a solution, I knew I needed to add some references. My guess is, that this is the source of your 'evil'.

I have added the references `'IronPython'` and `'Microsoft.Scripting'`, which come along with the installation of IronPython. The exact versions are v4.0.30319 (both IronPython and Microsoft Scripting).

So my Windows Forms application has one textBox and one button (it's just a test after all) and I copied in your example method called Calculate, in order to make sure we have the same, here is my version:

```
 public double Calculate(string script)
 {
   ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
   ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("import math" + Environment.NewLine + script, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect);
   return source.Execute<double>();
 }
```

In the eventhandler of my button I have placed the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    double outcome = Calculate("math.log(10)");
    tbOutcome.Text = string.Format("Outcome of log(10): {0}", outcome);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error occured...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }
}
```

When executing my application, the program does not show an error as yours, but it shows the an outcome that I did expect when calculating log(10) (assuming you are calculating a natural logarithm). My textBox contains:

```
Outcome of log(10): 2,30258509299405
```

So there is only one hint, try to find out if you have **different** versions of your ScriptEngine installed (I know there are a few more than just Microsoft.Scripting) and look at the references in your solution.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, Your guess was right it was dll hell. Surprisingly Runtime version of my dll was same as you mentioned(v4.0.30319) but version of all dlls was showing as 0.0.0.0 (These were dlls I had downloaded sometime before). I downloaded new dlls which have same Runtime Version (v4.0.30319) but Version is showing as 2.7.0.40 for IronPython and 1.1.0.20 for Microsoft.Dynamic and Microsoft.scripting dlls. Definitely these dlls are different but I don't understand why runtime version is same. Thanks for your answer it was great help.

Comment: Yes, Pyhton calculates natural log by default. For log with base 10, base can be supplied as second argument.

Comment: I have been in trouble with wrong assemblies and references before, so I am always having an eye on that. I am glad that it helped though!

Answer (score 2):

Python is case sensitive, and, there is no class named just `Math`.. only `System.Math`

so to get what you want, you need to use this import statement: `from System import Math` or `import System.Math as Math`

both would get you the same result...

Comment: Thanks Shlomi, I was using System.Math as well it was working fine when I called method as System.Math.Log(). I wanted to use Python style as our user were more used to writing as math.Log() rather than System.Math.Log(). However this problem is now solved as I am now using "from System import Math" and now user can just write Log() for script to be evaluated. Thanks your response, it was very helpful hence I am marking as answer.

Comment: Apologies Shlomi, though your answer was very helpful but I believe RvdV79's answer was more appropriate for my problem.

Comment: Oh, I see now... these are actually two different modules (System.Math is .Net type, and math is python module...)... I'm "too" used to .Net, and its Math class